# Maximizing JInternalFrame Windows Look and Feel maximizes all JInternalFrame

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel, jinternalframe, maximize-window

In the SSCCE below, you can see that if you maximize one of the `JInternalFrame`s, then it maximizes them both. This only (AFAIK) happens with the "Windows" `LookAndFeel` (if you omit the `LookAndFeel` code, it works as expected).

To reproduce:

1. Run the SSCCE below.
2. Maximize one of the `JInternalFrame`s.
3. Close (X) the one you maximized
4. Observe the other one was maximized as well.

Is there any way to stop this behavior? Is this a bug?

SSCCE:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.JDesktopPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JInternalFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

class Test2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Windows".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JDesktopPane jdp = new JDesktopPane();
        jdp.setBackground(Color.gray);
        frame.add(jdp);
        jdp.setVisible(true);
        frame.setExtendedState(frame.getExtendedState()|JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH );
        frame.setVisible(true);

        JInternalFrame jiffy1 = new JInternalFrame("Jiffy1", true, true, true, true);
        jdp.add(jiffy1);
        JLabel jiffy1_label = new JLabel("Jiffy1");
        jiffy1_label.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        jiffy1_label.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", 0, 50));
        jiffy1.add(jiffy1_label);
        jiffy1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,300));
        jiffy1.setVisible(true);
        jiffy1.pack();
        centerJIF(jdp, jiffy1);

        JInternalFrame jiffy2 = new JInternalFrame("Jiffy2", true, true, true, true);
        jdp.add(jiffy2);
        JLabel jiffy2_label = new JLabel("Jiffy2");
        jiffy2_label.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        jiffy2_label.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", 0, 50));
        jiffy2.add(jiffy2_label);
        jiffy2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,200));
        jiffy2.setVisible(true);
        jiffy2.pack();
        centerJIF(jdp, jiffy2);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    private static void centerJIF(JDesktopPane jdp, JInternalFrame jiffy) {
        Dimension desktopSize = jdp.getSize();
        Dimension VInternalFrameSize = jiffy.getSize();
        int width = (desktopSize.width - VInternalFrameSize.width) / 2;
        int height = (desktopSize.height - VInternalFrameSize.height) / 2;
        jiffy.setLocation(width, height);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is an issue with the Windows look and feel `DesktopManager`

Comment: @MadProgrammer  *"this is an issue with the Windows look and feel"*  It it?  By that I mean, do other internal frame based Windows apps. do the same thing(1)?  If so, it hardly seems like 'an issue' as opposed to simply complying with that Look and Feel.  1) That is not a rhetorical question, I really don't know the answer.

Comment: @AndrewThompson This could actually be the way it was designed (sorry I was trying to find out why we ditched it).  We switched from metal look and feel to Windows and stumbled on this issue, so no, other look and feels do it differently.  Is in standard to Windows...hmm, don't know MDIs were depreciated with Windows 3.1.  We switched to using the `DefaultDesktopManager`, can't remember if we modified it or not though...

Comment: @AndrewThompson Given the fact that the only MDI application I can find is Excel, it's hardly an ample cross section, but no, it doesn't behaviour in this manner.  Maximising a single window does not change the state of the other windows within the desktop...so, unless this feature changed between...XP and 7, it's not following what would be considered standard operating expectations...or even user expectations - but that's less of an issue with that regards

Comment: @MadProgrammer  Thanks for clarifying that it is **not** how a standard Windows app. would behave.

Comment: @MadProgrammer, Actually, I just tested it in Excel and Excel **does indeed** behave in this way. Also, I tried it in Quickbooks and Quickbooks does the same thing. So, perhaps this IS a Windows specification. DUMB!

Comment: I'll add: I'm not entirely certain what platform Quickbooks is written on. It does look a lot like a `Swing` application, though, and I've always suspected that it is. I think we can rest assured that Excel ain't written in Java, though.

Comment: @ryvantage Under what version of Windows and Excel? I couldn't get it to work. I was able to restore one window (neither max or min) max the other without effect the first. I did the same thing with the first window minimised without issue

Comment: @MadProgrammer, Windows 7, Excel 2010. NOTE: If you maximize then RESTORE, it will appear like nothing is amiss. However, if you maximize then CLOSE, you should see the other window maximized as well.

Comment: Like Sandra Bullocks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Windows DesktopManager there's a feature (in my opinion a bug...)  that maximize all frames when you maximize one frame.

from [WindowsDesktopManager.java](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/com/sun/java/swing/plaf/windows/WindowsDesktopManager.java.html) (Java 7) from line 62

```
... 
public void activateFrame(JInternalFrame f) {
    JInternalFrame currentFrame = currentFrameRef != null ? 
        currentFrameRef.get() : null;
    try {
        super.activateFrame(f);
        if (currentFrame != null && f != currentFrame) {
```

> ```
>             // If the current frame is maximized, transfer that 
>             // attribute to the frame being activated.
> ```

```
            if (currentFrame.isMaximum() &&
        (f.getClientProperty("JInternalFrame.frameType") !=
        "optionDialog") ) {
                //Special case.  If key binding was used to select next
                //frame instead of minimizing the icon via the minimize
                //icon.
                if (!currentFrame.isIcon()) {
                    currentFrame.setMaximum(false);
                    if (f.isMaximizable()) {
                        if (!f.isMaximum()) {
                            f.setMaximum(true);
                        } else if (f.isMaximum() && f.isIcon()) {
                            f.setIcon(false);
                        } else {
                            f.setMaximum(false);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if (currentFrame.isSelected()) {
                currentFrame.setSelected(false);
            }
        }

        if (!f.isSelected()) {
            f.setSelected(true);
        }
    } catch (PropertyVetoException e) {}
    if (f != currentFrame) {
        currentFrameRef = new WeakReference(f);
    }
}
...
```

so you can reinstall DefaultDesktopManager instead of WindowsDesktopManager and solve the problem:

```
JDesktopPane jdp = new JDesktopPane();
jdp.setDesktopManager(new DefaultDesktopManager());
```